# Underbrace issue (dotted line)

Tags: amsmath, packages, underbrace

I am having troubles with the appearance of the underbrace in the compiles pdf. I don't know if I may be missing a package or something similiar. Better to see an image of the trouble:

[image]

When the text I want to put down the formula exceeds some limit, the underbrace is divided into "parts" printed at different levels.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show us a short compilable TeX code we can play with ...

Comment: Might also be an idea to mention which pdf viewer you're using. But code example is most important